# Jquery .append() array results from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays, html

I'm having problems appending results from my xml parses to html elements correctly

**What I am trying to achieve:**

```
            <li>Tutorial
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="somelink">Tutorial 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="somelink">Tutorial 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="somelink">Tutorial 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="somelink">Tutorial 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Simple
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="somelink">Simple 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="somelink">Simple 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="somelink">Simple 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="somelink">Simple 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

**What I currently get from my code:**

```
                <li>Tutorial 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="somelink">Tutorial 1,Tutorial 2,Tutorial 3,Tutorial 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="somelink">Simple 1,Simple 2,Simple 3,Simple 4</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="somelink">More stuff from other arrays that should be seperate...</a></li>         
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Simple
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="somelink">Simple 1,Simple 2,Simple 3,Simple 4</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="somelink">More stuff from other arrays that should be seperate...</a></li>         
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
    console.log("searching xml");  
$(data).find("plist > dict > array > dict").each(function()  {

    var $board = $(this);
    console.log($board);

    //finds the title of each
    var title = $board.find('string').eq(0).text();
    //find the children of each dict
    console.log("finding children");
    var description = $board.find('array').contents('dict');
    var desarray = new Array();
    console.log("push to array");
    desarray.push(description.find('string:eq(1)').textChildren({stringDelimiter: ','}).split(','));
    console.log(description);   
    console.log(desarray);

    //desarray contains all the arrays;

    var  html = '<li>' +'<a href="somelink">' + desarray + '</a>'+'</li>';

    $("#list").append('<li>' + title + '<ul>');
    console.log("appended to title");
    $("#list li > ul").append(html);
    console.log("appended to title list");    
}); 

//refresh   
$('#list').listview('refresh');     
console.log("refreshed");
```

Because I am looping I appear to be appending results to my list when i wish not to. You can see in the 'Simple' list, once the 'Tutorial' elements are appended they do not appear in the next set of ul elements.

I'm stuck on what i should do to achieve what I want. I know the loop is causing an issue with multiple appends and that my array should probably be split somehow but i don't know how.

How would i print the results of each array only once? If I move the append methods outside the loop I only get the final result in the array.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT :**

The xml file is in .plist format. On the first loop the 'desarray' array fills with Tutorial 1,Tutorial 2, Tutorial 3, Tutorial 4. It is at this stage I want to print each index value and insert into a list element **once**. Instead I am looping again and returning Simple 1,Simple 2 etc and adding that to the current array 'desarray' which then prints again and causes the issue.

Sample of XML format, can include full file if not clear:

```
<dict>
<!--<key>DisplayTutorial</key>
    <string>Yes</string> -->
    <key>Grid</key>
    <string>...|...|...|</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Tutorial 1</string>
    <key>ON</key>
    <string>bar</string>
    <key>Pieces</key>
    <array>
        <string>Y11110000</string>
        <string>G11110000</string>
        <string>P11110000</string>
    </array>
    <key>UniqueName</key>
    <string>Tutorial/1.xml</string>
</dict><dict>
    <key>Grid</key>
    <string>....|OOOO|....|</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Tutorial 2</string>
    <key>Pieces</key>
    <array>
        <string>G11110000</string>
        <string>G11110000</string>
        <string>P11110000</string>
        <string>P11110000</string>
    </array>
    <key>UniqueName</key>
    <string>Tutorial/3.xml</string>
</dict><dict>
    <key>Grid</key>
    <string>...|.X.|...|</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Tutorial 3</string>
    <key>Pieces</key>
    <array>
        <string>G11110000</string>
        <string>G11110000</string>
        <string>P11110000</string>
        <string>P11110000</string>
    </array>
    <key>UniqueName</key>
    <string>Tutorial/4.xml</string>
</dict><dict>
    <key>Grid</key>
    <string>....|</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Tutorial 4</string>
    <key>Pieces</key>
    <array>
        <string>G11111111</string>
        <string>G00001111</string>
        <string>P00001111</string>
        <string>P11111111</string>
    </array>
    <key>UniqueName</key>
    <string>Tutorial/5.xml</string>
</dict></array> </dict>
```

Comment: What does your XML look like? That's going to be important for people to help solve how to select the proper information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery append array value to each list item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804755/jquery-append-array-value-to-each-list-item)