# JQuery append array value to each list item

Tags: jquery, append, html-lists, each

I have an unordered list like this:

```
<ul id="names-list">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

Lets say I want to add a name from this list to each of the `<li>` items:

```
var names = [ "Jon", "Nick", "Bill", "Tom" ];
```

And my code is like this:

```
$('#names-list li').each(function () {
 $(this).append(names);
});
```

But from some reason it doesn't work. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The each() method has an "index" argument. Use it to get the proper value in your list.

```
var names = [ "Jon", "Nick", "Bill", "Tom" ];
$('#names-list li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).text(names[index]);
});
```

​
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ESKh/

Answer (score 16):

Why has no one pointed out that basing the number of li's on the number of empty li's in the dom is a horrible way to do it? It's much better to generate the li's based on how many items there are in the array.

Try this instead:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <ul id="names-list">
        <!-- empty list -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var names = [ "Jon", "Nick", "Bill", "Tom" ];
var list = $("#names-list");
var parent = list.parent();

list.detach().empty().each(function(i){
    for (var x = 0; x < names.length; x++){
        $(this).append('<li>' + names[x] + '</li>');
        if (x == names.length - 1){
            $(this).appendTo(parent);
        }
    }
});
```

1. I define the names list, the list element, and the list elements parent
2. I detach the list from the dom so it doesn't refresh the dom
   for every list item added.
3. I empty the list in case there are already values in there
4. The each statement is more for triggering a function in relation to #names-list rather than handling multiple occurances of the list on the page
5. I run a loop going through each item in the array
6. I append a list item with each name in the array to the detached #names-list
7. On the final loop, I add the full list back into the dom by appending it to the parent element

**Update: Pure JS, modern syntax version**

If you are able to use modern code then this is a pure JS es6 version that I would use today:

```js
const names = [ "Jon", "Nick", "Bill", "Tom" ];
const listElem = document.querySelector("#names-list");

// Creates a string of HTML to inject rather than appending DOM elements
const listItemsHtml = names.map(name => `<li>${name}</li>`).join('');

// Replaces the current content in the list with the new content
listElem.innerHTML = listItemsHtml
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `index` property provided to the each function. Also, since it's text data you could use the `.text(...)` function:

```
$('#names-list li').each(function (index) {
  $(this).text(names[index]);
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vKCf/)

Answer (score -2):

```
var index = 0;
$('#names-list li').each(function () {
 $(this).html(names[index]);
 index = index + 1;
});
```